# How to have only an English keyboard layout in a CSS file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimetext4

Theme: Plugin Development Sublime Text.

I'll give you an example:

1. I opened the CSS file
2. Pressed "shift+3" or "shift+4"
3. And I want to get the characters: "shift+3" will print: "#" and "shift+4" will print: "$"
4. But if I have a Russian keyboard layout, I will get characters by clicking on: "shift+3" will print: "№", and "shift+4" will print: ";"

The essence of the question:
How to make sure that there is always an English keyboard layout in the -CSS file?

How it should work:

1. I opened a CSS file with a Russian keyboard layout
2. In the CSS file: I can't print Russian letters
3. In the CSS file: When pressing keyboard shortcuts, they work as if I have an English keyboard layout

I repeat the essence of the question:
How to make sure that there is always an English keyboard layout in the -CSS file?

Comment: How do you change from English to Russian and vice versa?

Comment: => windows+space

Comment: Thanks. There is a way to do this in Python (the language Sublime plugins are written in), but it requires the `pywin32` module, which you can get in Sublime with a little messing around. But before we get to that, can you please visit [this keyboard layout page](http://kbdlayout.info/#R) and tell me which of the Russian layouts you're using? It lists "Russian", "Russian - Mnemonic", and "Russian (typewriter)" as three possible options. As far as "English" keyboards go, are you using the [standard US layout](http://kbdlayout.info/kbdus)?

Comment: Also, do you want to switch back to Russian after a CSS file is no longer in focus or closed, or just leave it as US?

Comment: http://kbdlayout.info/kbdru my keyboard

Comment: It would be nice to make the language change back russian

Comment: Are you writing a plugin or prompting?

Comment: I'm looking into writing a plugin, if it's not too complex.